# flutter P2P communication over the network

Tags: flutter, dart, p2p

I read [this Android specific article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p) and was wondering if some applications existed for Flutter aswell.
I know it is possible to run native code in Flutter, but I'd prefer a Dart native solution. I've noticed [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_p2p#-readme-tab-) on `pub.dev` but I cannot make it work.

I've followed the posted example but I get a `MissingPluginException` for every call the plugin executes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do it by using this package .
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_connections